# Why the model does another request?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have route :

```
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('singleUser', params.user_id, {reload: true});
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.store.find('userNetwork', {userId: model.id});
  },
```

And two models:

models/single-user.js

```
userNetworks: DS.hasMany('userNetwork', {async: true})
```

models/user-network.js

```
singleUser: DS.belongsTo('singleUser'),
```

after that my model makes request to server:

```
GET "server/api/userNetworks?userId=270".
```

response from the server:

```
{"singleUsers":{"userNetworks":[40]}}
```

it's right, but makes another one request:

```
GET "server/app_dev.php/api/userNetworks/40".
```

Help me. Why is this happening ?

Ember v1.13.7
Ember-data v1.13.9

Comment: Because you're making 2 store.finds ?

Comment: I would put the second `find` in an `afterModel`, rather than `setupController`. That way you're sure that it's done loading before the transition is finalized and the template is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you assuming that `this.store.find('userNetwork', {userId: model.id});` should return the `userNetwork` from your model without an additional request because you've already gotten the model?

You're using `async: true` on the single-user `hasMany` relationship with `userNetworks`. This means you're specifying that you will request the related userNetworks separately, which means it will make a separate request.

Also, from the code you posted it looks like you most likely wanted to do:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  model.get("userNetworks");
},
```

Which will still make an additional request but is the correct way to get the related records.

If you don't want it to make additional requests, you could use the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and return the related `userNetworks` with each user model.

More on `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html)

P.S. @torazaburo is right on using `afterModel` vs. `setupController`.